# Error trying to install OneSignal plugin on iOS platform (ionic 3)

Tags: ios, xcode, ionic3, onesignal

I'm trying to install the OneSignal plugin in my project on the ios platform, it can install the plugin, but it always presents this error message when it performs the routine to add the platform.

---

```
Installing "onesignal-cordova-plugin" for ios

Failed to install 'onesignal-cordova-plugin': undefined

CordovaError: Promise rejected with non-error: 'Version should contain only numbers and dots'

    at cli.catch.err (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/cordova/bin/cordova:30:15)

    at process.internalTickCallback (internal/process/next_tick.js:77:7)

[ERROR] An error occurred while running subprocess cordova.
```

> My ionic info

cli packages: (/usr/local/lib/node_modules)

```
@ionic/cli-utils  : 1.19.2
ionic (Ionic CLI) : 3.20.0
```

global packages:

```
cordova (Cordova CLI) : 8.1.2 (cordova-lib@8.1.1)
```

local packages:

```
@ionic/app-scripts : 3.2.1
Cordova Platforms  : ios 4.5.5
Ionic Framework    : ionic-angular 3.9.2
```

System:

```
ios-deploy : 1.9.4 
Node       : v10.15.0
npm        : 6.4.1 
OS         : macOS High Sierra
Xcode      : Xcode 9.2 Build version 9C40b
```

Environment Variables:

```
ANDROID_HOME : not set
```

Misc:

```
backend : pro
```